# Pass connection string to dbcontext for Sqlite

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to pass the connection string to my dbcontext model.

I'm using the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite package.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Adds Entity FrameWork for SqlLite
    var config = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
    //How to pass the connection string, AddEntityFrameworkSqlite take no extra parameters
    //services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<ETLDataBase>(opt => opt.????)
    services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<ETLDataBase>();
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddScoped<IRepository<User>, AccountRepository>();
}
```

I didn't find a way to access to the `ContentRootPath` directly in the my dbcontext. I hardcoded the path of my DB in the `appsettings.json`, but even like this I can't pass the path to my model.

Here's my context model:

```
public class ETLDataBase: DbContext
{
    public ETLDataBase(DbContextOptions<ETLDataBase> options)
        : base(options)
    {}
    public DbSet<Datasouce> Datasources { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // I want to get my connection string in here
        //I can't access to the env.ContentRootPath
        var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connection);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If I do it like this in the `Startup.cs`:

`services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlite().AddDbContext<ETLDataBase>(options=> options.UseSqlite(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Default‌​Connection"]));`

And I remove the `OnConfiguring` function in the `ETLDataBase` class.

I have this error:

`No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`

Comment: You already receive it in the constructor. Why do you need it in `OnConfiguring`?

Comment: Do you have an idea how to access it from the constructor?

Comment: And how to pass it through the options in the `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: `AddDbContext` has two overloads, a parameterless one you use and which accepts a lambda: `.AddDbContext(options => options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));`

Comment: I think that I already tried this. Let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: When I do it like you said, I have this error message: `No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.`

Comment: What's your appsettings.json?